# Java 7 parallel execution is not improving performance of REST API using Countdown latch

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, parallel-processing, countdownlatch

I am writing a REST API in Java 7 to retrieve three items from database and send all three together to user as a response. When program runs in the sequential flow i.e. if I fetch one item then another then it is taking legitimate time for execution. But when I use multi-threading i.e. using three threads to fetch three items from database, it is taking more time for execution as compared to sequential. This issue is leading high **CPU usage** **more than 90%.**

example:

```
     Sequential: number of users 60
                 average execution time- 5149 milliseconds

     Parallel:   number of users 60
                 average execution time- 9544 milliseconds
```

I am using ExecutorService to achieve asynchronous execution mechanism and **Countdown latch** for synchronization of threads.

Why parallel execution taking more time then sequential? Is there any drawback of using Countdown latch here?

Code for execution of worker threads using Countdown latch :

```
List<Runnable> workers;

if (StringUtils.isBlank(typeCode)) {
    workers =          
    ItemManagerHelper.determineItemLookupWorkersByItemIdentifiers(Id, ids,
    effectiveStartDate, effectiveEndDate, errors, ItemUIList, dataMap);
    }
else {
     workers = ItemManagerHelper.determineItemLookupWorkersByItemType(Id, 
     ids,effectiveStartDate,effectiveEndDate, typeCode, errors, ItemUIList, 
     dataMap);
    }

ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool                                            
(workers.size());

CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(workers.size());

for (Runnable worker : workers) {
      ((ItemLookupThread) worker).setLatch(latch);
      threadPoolExecutor.submit(worker);
}

try {
      latch.await(threadTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
      error(this.getClass(), e, "Exception occurred while waiting for the 
           lookup child threads completion.");
} 
finally {
      threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
}
```

ItemLookupThread is my thread class:

```
public class ItemLookupThread implements Runnable {

private ItemProvider provider;
private long Id;
ItemsIdentifiers ids;
private long effectiveStartDate;
private long effectiveEndDate;
private Map<Object, Object> dataMap;
private List<BaseResponse.Error> errors;
private List<ItemUI> Items;
private CountDownLatch latch;

  public ItemLookupThread (ItemProvider provider, long Id, 
    ItemsIdentifiers ids,long effectiveStartDate,
    long effectiveEndDate, Map<Object, Object> dataMap,      
    List<ItemUI> Items, List<BaseResponse.Error> errors) {

      this.provider = provider;
      this.Id = Id;
      this.ids = ids;
      this.effectiveStartDate = effectiveStartDate;
      this.effectiveEndDate = effectiveEndDate;
      this.dataMap = dataMap;
      this.Items = Items;
      this.errors = errors;
    }

 @Override
 public void run() {
    try {
       debug(this.getClass(), "Item lookup started :" + 
       Thread.currentThread().getId());
       provider.lookup(Id, ids, effectiveStartDate, effectiveEndDate, 
       dataMap, Items, errors);
       debug(this.getClass(), "Item lookup completed :" + 
       Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    finally {
         if (latch != null) {
         latch.countDown();
         }
    }
  }

  public void setLatch(CountDownLatch latch) {
          this.latch = latch;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details - code snippets, what you changed, how you're using the latch, what the threads are doing, etc. As is your question is similar to "My car was making a weird noise, so I drove faster and it got worse, what's wrong?"

Comment: There are plenty of possibilities here, if you spawn too many threads for instance, the creation overhead as well as the context switching can consume a lot of resources, leading to a degradation of the observed throughput. As mentioned by @dimo414 without any other details, we can only hypothesize that either you are misusing threads, or that your application cannot be parallelized efficiently

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a huge amount of context switching going on.  My recommendation is to move the ExecutorService from being a method variable to being a field in your service (or controller) class.

```
private ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);


public void myServiceMethod() {

    List<Runnable> workers;

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(typeCode)) {
        workers =          
        ItemManagerHelper.determineItemLookupWorkersByItemIdentifiers(Id, ids,
        effectiveStartDate, effectiveEndDate, errors, ItemUIList, dataMap);
        }
    else {
         workers = ItemManagerHelper.determineItemLookupWorkersByItemType(Id, 
         ids,effectiveStartDate,effectiveEndDate, typeCode, errors, ItemUIList, 
         dataMap);
        }
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(workers.size());

    for (Runnable worker : workers) {
          ((ItemLookupThread) worker).setLatch(latch);
          threadPoolExecutor.submit(worker);
    }

    try {
          latch.await(threadTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
          error(this.getClass(), e, "Exception occurred while waiting for the 
               lookup child threads completion.");
    } 
    finally {
          threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
    }
}
```